# I can't send the customer ID from my table

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a problem sending the ID to the page clientMdodify.html from my table,this is what I did:

Clients.html,in which I call the clientModify.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-align:center" id="table" >
        <thead>
            <th align="center">Référence</th><th align="center">Nom</th><th>Prenom</th><th>Email</th><th>Adresse Facturation</th><th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr  ng-repeat="post in posts" >
                <td align="center">{{post.id}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{post.nom}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{post.email}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{post.adresse}}</td>
               <td align="center"><a ui-sref="app.modify">Modify</a></td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

this is config-router.js for the routes:

```
.state('app.modify', {
           url: 'client/modify/:customerID',
           templateUrl: 'tpl/clientMdodify.html,
           controller: 'editCtrl',
             resolve: {
            customer: function(services, $route){
            var customerID = $route.current.params.customerID;
            return services.getCustomer(customerID);
          }
        }
              })
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router',
    'ngRoute',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
]).factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
  var serviceBase = 'services/'
    var obj = {};
    obj.getCustomers = function(){
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'clients');
    }
    obj.getCustomer = function(customerID){
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'client?id=' + customerID);
    }

    obj.insertCustomer = function (customer) {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'insertClient', customer).then(function (results) {
        return results;
    });};

    obj.updateCustomer = function (id,customer) {
        return $http.post(serviceBase + 'updateClient', {id:id, customer:customer}).then(function (status) {
            return status.data;
        });
    };

    obj.deleteCustomer = function (id) {
        return $http.delete(serviceBase + 'deleteClient?id=' + id).then(function (status) {
            return status.data;
        });
    };

    return obj;   
}]).controller('editCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, services, customer) {

    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];

    var customerID = ($routeParams.customerID) ? parseInt($routeParams.customerID) : 0;
    $rootScope.title = (customerID > 0) ? 'Edit Customer' : 'Add Customer';
    $scope.buttonText = (customerID > 0) ? 'Update Customer' : 'Add New Customer';
      var original = customer.data;
      original._id = customerID;
      $scope.customer = angular.copy(original);
      $scope.customer._id = customerID;

      $scope.isClean = function() {
      $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
      $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
        return angular.equals(original, $scope.customer);
      }

      $scope.deleteCustomer = function(customer) {
      $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
      $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
        $location.path('/');
        if(confirm("Est ce que vous voulez supprimer ce client: "+$scope.customer._id)==true)
        services.deleteCustomer(customer.id);
      };

      $scope.saveCustomer = function(customer) {
    $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
      $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
        $location.path('/');
        if (customerID <= 0) {
            services.insertCustomer(customer);
        }
        else {
            services.updateCustomer(customerID, customer);
        }};})
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to send parameter with the **ui-sref** attribute like below:

```
<td align="center"><a ui-sref="app.modify({customerID: <your_customer_id>})">Modify</a></td>
```

Comment: If the **post.id** is the customerID that you wanted to send then write this instead **<your_customer_id>**.